# Re-install of pgAdmin4 on Ubuntu 18.04 does not prompt for user/password and local pgAdmin site not found

Tags: 18.04, apache2, postgresql, pgadmin

I initially followed instructions to install postgres and pgadmin4 from https://tecadmin.net/install-pgadmin4-on-ubuntu/ successfully.

I seemed to be able to get to the site at http://localhost/pgadmin4 but couldn't login.

After a few attempts to reset the pgadmin4 user/password.  I thought okay I'll just remove/reinstall it with:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2
```

When I re-installed **I am not reprompted for the pgadmin user** info AND the url which previously worked now gives a 404 not found.

I have restarted the server.

I have rebooted after reinstallation.

I did a recursive search for pgadmin to remove any trace of it from my pc before reinstalling on machine.

I've looked in /etc/apache2 sites-enable, mods-enabled, config-enabled etc... to see if there are traces of the previous install.

I've searched here and stackoverflow and the web generally but not having much success.

Comment: okay wow, that was it!  Thanks, your is the accepted answer:  sudo apt-get **purge** pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2 allowed for a successful re-installation

Answer (score 0):

You can find your user details on the SQLlite db file.
The file that you should open with SQLlite3 is /var/lib/pgadmin4/pgadmin4.db

run the command: 
`sqlite3 /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db`

```
sqlite> .tables 
sqlite> select * from user;
```

And you will see there your username and hashed password.